# How do I reply to people wondering why their question was downvoted even when the same type of question were used to be well-received earlier?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Today, someone asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70282894/14425501) on Stack Overflow, and it received 3 down-votes.
In 2015, someone had asked the same-type-of-question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38260113/14425501), and it received 41 up-votes.

In the comments section, he/she asked this:

> why people have down-voted my question even the same type of question
> were never down-voted?

How do I answer this?

Comment: Many old questions get upvoted a lot despite being rubbish. Asking for someone to provide you a full implementation of some machine learning model isn't the way of SO  - it is much too broad. You must ask specific, targeted questions.

Comment: For one thing, you don't have to answer it. You're [not required to provide feedback beyond voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325416/248731), and it's probably best to not speculate why other people chose to vote the way they did (beyond the guidance on the tooltip).

Comment: You don't. There is no need to reply to comments about downvotes. It's not unlikely the user will think you downvoted their post, even if you didn't. At most, provide feedback in ways to improve their question, if you can think of any.

Comment: For what it's worth, the second question linked is also not that great, but it was asked during the boom of TensorFlow, which attracted a great load of questions that now have a high score, in spite of their apparent low research effort or lack of focus.

Comment: @E_net4thecurator that's true. I got it.

Comment: Two simple steps: Flag -> It's no longer needed.

Comment: The rest of the feedback also applies. Do not feel inclined to justify "why the downvote", but rather focus on describing any potential issues with the question that you find and wish to communicate. And flag any "why the downvote" comments as no longer needed.

Comment: Do not ever respond to questions phrased like that; they're a landmine ready to go off. A person asking a question like that is like not looking for an answer, they're looking for someone to blame. Only respond if someone asks *what can be improved*. Then you have a reasonable certainty that they are actually seeking to improve something.

Comment: There is [a new revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70282894/revisions) (actual code added).

Comment: *[Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/tour)* and *[Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour)* also take machine learning questions. Though [many seem](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/104912/) [to be](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/104914/there-is-overfitting-in-my-model) [pretty broad](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/47098/) [and/or](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/555479/) [underspecified](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/555456/making-predictions-with-support-vector-classification).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Flag the comment as "no longer needed", and go about your day.

Answer (score 4):

If you're feeling adventurous you can still reply to the comment. Maybe the OP is a reasonable person that just wants to know what causes the different attitude towards two questions that seem similar. If they understand better they can ask better questions in the future. It can also help them to feel less mistreated and to maintain a good mood/less fear in participating on SO.

I don't have a lot of experience participating in comment conversations on SO, but on my main site (TeX.SE) I do this a lot and it usually works out fine.

Note that it can also backfire and end badly, when the OP is *not* interested in an actual explanation and just expresses their frustration about not having their question answered. Of course *then* is a good moment to walk away from the situation (and possibly flag rude behavior of the OP against you).

Comment: It's really not worth the effort.  It's not even your responsibility to do this.

Comment: @Makoto It is indeed not your responsibility (I don't think users have any kind of responsibility towards other users other than following the Code of Conduct) but that doesn't mean it's not worth the effort - sometimes it isn't, other times it is.

Comment: In my ten years on this site, it's almost never been worth it. The company should really step up and explain why downvoting happens more often and spare the people who know when to apply it as opposed to subjecting us to those users' ire.

Comment: _"sometimes it isn't, other times it is"_ I am usually not in favor of playing Russian Roulette. But to each their own.